# Is it possible to write URLs to RFID tags with the RC522? If so, how?

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I've been trying to research to answer this question for a long time, but could not figure out the answer. I know how to code like bytes of information, but not URLs. More specifically, when you code information into a MiFare RFID tag with the RC522 device, each byte goes into separate byte blocks of a sector. They are not combined, meaning the link cannot be read. How do you overcome this and is this even possible?

Comment: http://asciitable.com/

Comment: that makes sense now ... why is it that your question does not say that? .... edit your question and delete the comments